# Existence of sections of sphere bundles.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I am reading this [article](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/li4.pdf), could you please tell me where I can find the proof of Theorem 2.1.1?

> Theorem 2.1.1. Let $\pi: S \rightarrow M$ be a $(d-1)$-sphere bundle over a closed manifold $M$ of dimension $d$. Suppose that the structure group of $S$ can
> be reduced to the orthogonal group $\mathrm{O}(d, \mathbb{R})$, then there exists a smooth map $s: M \rightarrow S$ such that $s \in \Gamma(M \backslash I, S)$, where $I$ is discrete.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably do not mean that $s$ is smooth on the entire $M$, only outside of $I$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan e...I don’t know the original theorem.

Comment: It does not matter: If you have a smooth map defined on the entire $M$ and it is a section outside of a discrete subset then it is a section everywhere, which clearly is impossible. I think you are either quoting incorrectly or the author made a mistake.

Comment: I checked, the mistake is indeed not yours but of the author of the paper.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you! Could you please explain why it can’t be a section everywhere? And do you know how to fix this theorem?

Comment: Yes, I know and will write a solution later when I have time. As for an example, already the unit tangent bundle of the 2D sphere is an example when a section does not exist, it does exist after you remove a point.

Comment: By the way, please change the title of the question to something more informative, say, “existence of sections of sphere bundles.”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the correct statement:

Theorem. Suppose that $M$ is a smooth closed $n$-manifold, $\xi=(\pi:S\to M)$ is a smooth fiber bundle with fibers $S^{n-1}$, whose structure group is reduced to the orthogonal group $O(n)$. Then there is a finite subset $I\subset M$ and a smooth section $s$ of this bundle over $M\setminus I$.

Proof. By the assumption, the bundle $\xi$ is associated with a principal $O(n)$-bundle over $M$, hence, there is a rank $n$ real vector bundle $\eta=(E\to M)$ equipped with a (fiberwise) metric, such that $\xi$ is the unit sphere bundle of $\eta$.

Now, we can start the actual proof. First, take the zero section $\sigma_0$ of $\eta$. Then perturb it to a smooth section $\sigma$ of the same bundle $\eta$ which is transversal to the zero section. (Such perturbation arguments you can find in any good differential topology textbook, say, in Guillemin and Pollack. Incidentally, it is a good exercise to see that if $\sigma$ is a smooth map $M\to E$ sufficiently close to a section in $C^{1}$ topology, then $\sigma$ itself is the precomposition of a section with a diffeomorphism $M\to M$ close to $id_M$.) By transversality and since $E$ has dimension $2n$, it follows that the set of zeroes of $\sigma$ is a 0-dimensional submanifold $I$ in $M$. By compactness of $M$, $I$ has to be finite. Now, on $M\setminus I$, replace $\sigma$ with
$$
s=\sigma/|\sigma|,
$$
where the norm is the fiberwise norm on $\eta$. Thus, $s$ is the required section of $\xi$. qed.

The argument I gave is very standard, it is used for instance to define index of a vector field, in the case when $\eta$ is the tangent bundle of $M$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't believe your “good exercise,” however, even with the trivial bundle.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Yes, I was sloppy: It is a section up to precomposition with a diffeomorphism of the base which is close to the identity.

Comment: Rght, now I agree..